# Obtener queryset para todos los templates

Tags: python, django, django-views

En la cabecera tengo un `<select>` con varias opciones que obtengo de la **base de datos**, y como se muestra en todos los templates, necesito recuperarlos en cada una de las **views**.

Hay alguna forma de crear un **QuerySet** global desde el que se pueda acceder desde todos los templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te entiendo muy bien en cuanto al `<select>`. Por otra parte para acceder a una QuerySet desde cualquier template(`context`), un QuerySet "global", como lo mencionas, habría que extender el contexto global.

Para hacerlo que crear un archivo llamado `context_processors.py` en tu aplicación.

En el archivo `context_processors.py` crea una función que retornara el QuerySet:

```
from .models import MyModel

def ctx_dict(request):
    return {'QuerySet': MyModel.objects.filter(...)}
```

Ahora hay que registrarlo en el `settings.py` para que se inyecte en el contexto global, haciendo referencia a la función, que en este caso es `ctx_dict`, de la siguiente manera:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'your_app.context_processors.ctx_dict', # <- AQUI!!
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Una ves hecho esto desde cualquier template tendrás acceso al QuerySet, un ejemplo:

```
<div>{{ QuerySet }}</div>
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Perfecto, justo lo que estaba buscando!!